# RetroFit2 how can i use @Query

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

i'm having these erro when i try do make a call in retrofit2

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "{login},{senha}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
                                                                                             for method usuarioService.verificarUsuario
```

How can i use the method @Query, in these code?

```
 @GET("/verificarUsuario/?{login},{senha}")
Call<String> verificarUsuario(@Query("login") String login, @Query("senha") String senha);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url which you are passing to as

`@GET("/verificarUsuario/?{login},{senha}")`, must be as

```
@GET("/verificarUsuario")
```

---

Read about [**How to Use QueryMap**](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-add-multiple-query-parameter-with-querymap)